# How do I specify which collections are being queried in AQL?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql

lets imagine I have this graph
[image]

and I want to query for all the *partners* connected to an user

```
 WITH partner  
 FOR u IN user
   FILTER u._name == @user_name 
    FOR v IN OUTBOUND user GRAPH 'accounts'
      RETURN v
```

this query works when `@user_name == Client` because it's only connected to *partners* but when `@user_name == Admin` the *profiles* are returned also, when I expected an empty list (because user `Admin` has no partners)

Am I using the keyword `WITH` in the correct manner?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `WITH` keyword is to specify the [collections involved in a traversal](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html#graph-traversals-in-a-cluster), so that they can be read-locked at query start instead of lazily during traversal, which can lead to dead lock situations. It it required for traversals in a cluster.

It does not affect the query result. If you want to return paths that end at nodes from a certain collection only, use a filter with [IS_SAME_COLLECTION()](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Functions/Document.html#issamecollection):

```
WITH user, partner, profile
FOR u IN user
  FILTER u._name == @user_name 
  FOR v IN OUTBOUND user GRAPH 'accounts'
    FILTER IS_SAME_COLLECTION('partner', v)
    RETURN v
```